# In R, how to convert aggregate for data.frame into aggregate for a data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, data.table

I'm wondering how to convert an `aggregate` on a `data.frame` to work on a `data.table`.

For example, I have a `data.table` called `mydt`:

```
Date       ,     Time  , Value
1899-01-01 ,  4:00:00  ,    1
1899-01-01 ,  4:01:00  ,    2
1899-01-01 ,  4:02:00  ,    3
1899-01-01 ,  4:03:00  ,    4
1899-01-01 ,  4:04:00  ,    5
1900-08-22 , 22:00:00  ,  101
1900-08-22 , 22:01:00  ,  102
2013-08-29 ,  4:00:00  , 1000
2013-02-29 ,  4:02:00  , 1001
2013-02-29 ,  4:03:00  , 1002
```

I want to group by `Date` to produce a `data.table` in the the following format:

```
Date      , Vector(variable length)
1899-02-28, c(1,2,3,4,5)
1900-08-22, c(101,102)
1900-08-22, c(1000,1001,1002)
```

If I was dealing with a `data.frame`, the correct command would be:

```
temp <- aggregate(Value ~ Date, mydt, as.vector)
```

What is the equivalent command if I am dealing with a `data.table`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group by `Date` and use `list(Value)` within the `list` to get the result as a list.

```
dt[, list(Value=list(Value)), by=Date]

#           Date     Value
# 1: 1899-01-01  1,2,3,4,5
# 2: 1900-08-22    101,102
# 3: 2013-08-29       1000
# 4: 2013-02-29  1001,1002
```